# How can I add two strings into an int in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this code that helps me getting information from texts files , the problem is that i cant get to add all the strings founds in the texts files into one int.
in the first Entrada.txt i have a 23 and in the second one i have 45.

How can i add those 2 numbers together?

```
foreach(var impressora in ListaImp)
{
    var Entrada = File.ReadAllText(impressora + @"\Entrada.txt");

    MessageBox.Show("Entrada : " + Entrada);
}
```

Output: 2345.

I want it to be 23 + 45 = 68

Comment: Why you use one file for each number?

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn about `int.Parse`... the fact that you're doing it in a loop or that the string is in a file is irrelevant to the main concern of wanting to convert a string into an integer.

Comment: If you have integer numbers as text, use `int.Parse(s)` to get them as numbers, then you can add them as normal.

Comment: There is no strings addition in your code. How did you get 2345?

Comment: I misunderstood the question in my previous answer below.  To echo the above comment, what are your actual values here?  If the string you're reading in is "2345" then how would you know that it's supposed to be two 2-digit numbers?

Comment: I have two text files and they contain 2 strings - 23 45. if i add them to a label with += Entrada it gives me the 2345, i forgot to mention that

Comment: @TimSchmelter its like a system, Impressora means Printer , every printer has it own folder that contains all the information about the printer, thats why i have one file for each number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int sub = 0;
foreach(var impressora in ListaImp)
        {
          var Entrada = File.ReadAllText(impressora + @"\Entrada.txt");
          sub += int.Parse(Entrada); 

        }
MessageBox.Show(sub.ToString());
```